# How to show all answers even if there is no participants in one of them?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following database design:

```
Employee Table: EmployeeID, Name, OrgCode
Department Table: OrgCode, DepartName
CompleteSurvey Table: ID, RespondantID, QuestionsAnswersID
Questions Table: QuestionID, Question
Answers Table: AnswerID, Answer
QuestionsAnswers Table: ID, QuestionID, AnswerID
```

Each question has different multiple choices. Most of the questions have the same choices such as (Agree, Disagree). I want to write the query that shows the question with all of its choices and the number of participants in each choice even if it is zero. ***I wrote the query and it shows all answers of the question even if there no one choose one of the answers, but the query shows NULL in the Questions column besides the answers with no participants and I don't know why***. Any help please?

My Query:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID) AS [Total Number of Participants], dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question
FROM         dbo.CompleteSurvey INNER JOIN
                      dbo.QuestionsAnswers ON dbo.CompleteSurvey.QuestionsAnswersID = dbo.QuestionsAnswers.ID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Questions ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.QuestionID = dbo.Questions.QuestionID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Answers ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID = dbo.Answers.AnswerID
GROUP BY dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question
```

**UPDATE:**

***The query should show the number of participants of each department in the question with all its answers, so how to do that?***

My Updated Query:

```
SELECT     COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID) AS [Total Number of Participants], dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question, 
                      dbo.Departments.DepartmentName
FROM         dbo.Employees INNER JOIN
                      dbo.CompleteSurvey ON dbo.Employees.EmployeeID = dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Departments ON dbo.Employees.OrgCode = dbo.Departments.OrgCode RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Questions INNER JOIN
                      dbo.QuestionsAnswers ON dbo.Questions.QuestionID = dbo.QuestionsAnswers.QuestionID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Answers ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID = dbo.Answers.AnswerID ON dbo.CompleteSurvey.QuestionsAnswersID = dbo.QuestionsAnswers.ID
GROUP BY dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question, dbo.Departments.DepartmentName
```

***But the problem with it doesn't show the department. It should show the number of participants of each department in each question with all of its answers even if there is no participant in one of that answers.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuestionAnswers is the table required to get the answers, but because you are using an `INNER JOIN` from CompleteSurvey to QuestionAnswers you are eliminating all rows in QuestionAnswers with no corresponding row in CompleteSurvey. I think this will work if you change the join between them to `RIGHT OUTER`.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID) AS [Total Number of Participants], 
        dbo.Answers.Answer, 
        dbo.Questions.Question
FROM    dbo.CompleteSurvey 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.QuestionsAnswers 
            ON dbo.CompleteSurvey.QuestionsAnswersID = dbo.QuestionsAnswers.ID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Questions 
            ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.QuestionID = dbo.Questions.QuestionID 
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Answers 
            ON dbo.QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID = dbo.Answers.AnswerID
GROUP BY dbo.Answers.Answer, dbo.Questions.Question
```

**However** I would recommend switching the order you are joining round in, The below will eliminate one OUTER JOIN, which on the whole do not perform as well as INNER JOINs. It also (in my option) makes for a much easier to read query when LEFT JOINs are used instead of right joins.

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.CompleteSurvey.RespondantID) AS [Total Number of Participants], 
        dbo.Answers.Answer, 
        dbo.Questions.Question
FROM    dbo.Questions
        INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionAnswers
            ON Questions.QuestionID = QuestionAnswers.QuestionID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Answers
            ON QuestionAnswers.AnswerID = Answers.AnswerID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.CompleteSurvey
            ON QuestionAnswers.QuestionAnswersID = CompleteSurvey.QuestionAnswersID
GROUP BY Answers.Answer, Questions.Question
```

---

**UPDATED REQUIREMENTS**

If I am understanding the requirements correctly you just need to join Employee and Department to questionAnswer to get the department. This could be done just by left joining twice, however I have moved it to a subquery for no other reason than I like to use INNER JOINs where I can, so if there is a way I can rearrange a query with less OUTER JOINs I will do it:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT CompleteSurvey.RespondantID) AS [Total Number of Participants], 
        Answers.Answer, 
        Questions.Question,
        DepartName
FROM    dbo.Questions
        INNER JOIN dbo.QuestionsAnswers
            ON Questions.QuestionID = QuestionsAnswers.QuestionID
        INNER JOIN dbo.Answers
            ON QuestionsAnswers.AnswerID = Answers.AnswerID
        CROSS JOIN Departments
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  OrgCode, QuestionsAnswersID, RespondantID
            FROM    dbo.CompleteSurvey
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Employees
                        ON EmployeeID = RespondantID
        ) CompleteSurvey
            ON QuestionsAnswers.ID = CompleteSurvey.QuestionsAnswersID
            AND Departments.OrgCode = CompleteSurvey.OrgCode
GROUP BY Answers.Answer, Questions.Question, DepartName
ORDER BY Questions.Question, Answers.Answer, DepartName
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. However, I got a new requirement related to this query and I could not do it within your query. Could you please see my updated question above?

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work with me and I don't know why. Could you please test your query?

Comment: I added the updated query that I am working on it but still doesn't provide me with the results.

Comment: I've updated my revised answer so that it will run. However it does return the same results as the query you have provided. What do you mean by "Doesn't provide me with the results". Can you be more specific about exatly what is not right about it.

Comment: It still shows NULL value in the department name field. What I want is to list the first department, for example department A, and shows the question will of its answers with showing the number of participants in each answer. Then, it should the second department and so on. Is it possible?

Comment: Right, I think I have cracked it now. i've added a `CROSS JOIN` to department so that it now shows **ALL** Combinations of Question, Answer and Department, so department will now show even if nobody in that department has answered the question.